# Cannot understand why window will not open when adding `self.`

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a tkinter application with multiple frames.

In my code, adding `self.` (as in `self.name`) in front of any of the declarations in the `settings` class means that the window will not open. Why?

```
class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switchFrame(settings)

def switchFrame(self, frame_class):
       new_frame = frame_class(self)
       if self._frame is not None:
           self._frame.destroy()
       self._frame = new_frame
       self._frame.pack()

class settings(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

    lengthSliderTitle = "Set the race length in metres"

    tk.Label(master, text = lengthSliderTitle).grid(column= 0, row = 1)
    raceLengthSlider = tk.Scale(master, from_=1000, to=10000, length= 600, tickinterval = 1000, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
    raceLengthSlider.grid(column = 0, row = 2)

    racersNumSliderTitle = "Set the amount of racers"

    tk.Label(master, text = racersNumSliderTitle).grid(column = 0, row = 4)
    racersNumSlider = tk.Scale(master, from_= 2, to= 50, length = 600, tickinterval = 5, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
    racersNumSlider.grid(column= 0, row = 5)

    finishScreen1btn = tk.Button(master, text = "Done", command = self.finishScreen1)
    finishScreen1btn.grid(column = 0, row = 6)

def finishScreen1():
    currentRace.length = raceLengthSlider.get()
    currentRace.numRacers = racersNumSlider.get()
    master.switchFrame(animalsettings).pack()
```

`switchFrame` is what the main app uses to switch between frames. Each frame has a structure similar to the `settings` class.

The line `finishScreen1btn = tk.Button(master, text = "Done", command = self.finishScreen1)` is what makes the window not appear. What happens is that no errors are printed into the Python terminal, but no window opens either.

Comment: Please don't post code as images

Comment: @Norrius Fixed that. IDLE on Mac does not allow copying and pasting for some reason.

Comment: Is this really how your code is indented? There are lots of indentation errors.

Comment: After correcting the indentation and creating a callback function for the `finishScreen1btn` The program runs and displays the window. After adding `.self` to the names in `settings()` the window is displayed like before. Can you please post the code that produces the error.

Comment: @figbeam It looks like I used the wrong name for the callback function when making `finishScreen1btn`. The callback function is meant to be `finishScreen1`, so I edited the question. Also, I added the error-producing code in to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the window to not show. The only significant error I could find was not saving the name of the parent in the class `settings()` properly. See below:

```
import tkinter as tk

class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switchFrame(settings)

    def switchFrame(self, frame_class):
           new_frame = frame_class(self)
           if self._frame is not None:
               self._frame.destroy()
           self._frame = new_frame
           self._frame.grid()

class settings(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master    # Save referense to an instance variable

        self.lengthSliderTitle = "Set the race length in metres"

        tk.Label(master, text = self.lengthSliderTitle).grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.raceLengthSlider = tk.Scale(master, from_=1000, to=10000,
                                         length=600, tickinterval=1000,
                                         orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.raceLengthSlider.grid(column=0, row=2)

        self.racersNumSliderTitle = "Set the amount of racers"

        tk.Label(master, text=self.racersNumSliderTitle).grid(column=0, row=4)
        self.racersNumSlider = tk.Scale(master, from_=2, to=50, length=600,
                                        tickinterval=5, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.racersNumSlider.grid(column=0, row=5)

        self.finishScreen1btn = tk.Button(master, text="Done",
                                          command=self.finishScreen1)
        self.finishScreen1btn.grid(column=0, row=6)

    def finishScreen1(self):
        self.currentRace_length = self.raceLengthSlider.get()
        self.currentRace_numRacers = self.racersNumSlider.get()
        self.master.switchFrame(animalsettings).pack()  # Call master object

app = app()
app.mainloop()
```

The function `animalsettings` is not implementet so that still produces an error.

Comment: Thank you! There must be a problem with my tkinter or python version then.